# Error missing when inferring `never` return type from anonymous function

Tags: typescript

Why is that the following code in TypeScript (Version 4.3.2 or 4.4.0-nightly) has different outcomes when inferring the `never` return type, see comments in the code below:

```
const willThrowException:(message:string)=>never = (message)=> {
    throw new Error(message);
}

try {
    willThrowException('some message');
    willThrowException('another message'); // OK: compiler will error 'Unreachable code detected'
} catch(e) {}

const willThrowExceptionToo = (message:string):never=> {
    throw new Error(message);
}

try {
    willThrowExceptionToo('some message');
    willThrowExceptionToo('another message'); // NOT OK: compiler will not error
} catch(e) {}
```

The typescript compiler recognises in the autocomplete that the function is of return type `never`:

[image]

However it doesn't prevent the execution flow the same way as the declared type (which it is more verbose but closer to best practices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the TypeScript compiler. [It does code path analysis before type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37885#issuecomment-612992229), and the second example doesn't work because even though it's strongly typed, it's not explicitly typed.

I wish this was better documented, but you can [read through this pull request for more information about this limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33622).

If you don't like explicitly providing a type annotation as shown in your first example, you can also create an overload that defines the throw condition statically and explicitly.

```js
function willThrowException (message: string): never;
function willThrowException (message: string) {
    throw new Error(message);
}
```

Looking at the above, it's wild that the overload is explicit enough and the return type isn't. Perhaps this is worth a discussion on TypeScript's Discord or GitHub issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still looking for the reference (CFA occurs before type inference) in the material you quoted. The only thing I found so far was the clause "explicit never return type annotation" from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695 which explains the requirement for the missing CFA effect, but the limitation reason you provided still a bit mysterious to me at least. Note the example you provided is not related to the anonymous function. Thanks again.

Comment: I added [a reference for CFA coming before the type inference phase](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37885#issuecomment-612992229). And yes, I don't recall there being overloads for arrow function expressions, but there may be.

Comment: Thanks @evelynhathaway, super helpful. I've also seen discussions about eventually putting a warning(or something like that) on inferred `never` types, the reference you added also uses anonymous functions. Cheers.